# Yii 2 No Refresh on SideNav Click

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii2

I have a SideNav in my `bizadmin.php` view:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3" id="sidenav">
    <?php
        echo SideNav::widget([
        'type' => 'default',
        'encodeLabels' => false,

        //'heading' => $heading,
        'items' => [
            ['label' => 'Add Staff', 'icon' => 'user', 'url' => ['/user/index']],
            ['label' => 'Store Configuration', 'icon' => 'cog', 'url' => ['/store/index']],
            ['label' => 'Add Transaction', 'icon' => 'duplicate', 'url' => ['/transaction/index']],
            ['label' => 'Add Account', 'icon' => 'book', 'url' => ['/account/index']],
            ],
        ]);        
    ?>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-7">
        <h2 id="bizstorename">Store Name</h2>
        <h5>This is a store description. You can put anything here as long as it describes your store.</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

It looks like this:

[image: no-refresh on sidenav click]

Is there a way that when I click an item on my SideNav, it will **NOT** redirect to another page, but instead, a page will just be loaded inside a `div` (for example, in my case, inside `<div class="col-xs-7">`) beside the SideNav **without refreshing the entire page.**

I think I need to use jQuery or Ajax of some sort but I don't know how. Please let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's `.load` method to fetch a page and then append to `#result`:

```
$script = "
    $('#sidenav ul li a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#result').load(url);
    });
";
$this->registerJs($script, $this::POS_READY);
```

See [jQuery's docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for more info.

Comment: yeah, just add the id `result` to your div like so: `<div class="col-xs-7" id="result">`